# How to preserve whitespace in dynamically added javascript DOM element without using CSS?

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, whitespace

When adding in text with small whitespace appended to it for alignment purposes the whitespace is trimmed off (the whitespace is added in c# so by the time it gets to front end Javascript it cannot be edited - ***it would be nice to just use some CSS to do this but it is not an option***).

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
var zlp = document.getElementById("testDiv")
zlp.innerHTML = "hello                hello"
var zzz = document.createTextNode("hello                hello")
zlp.appendChild(zzz)
```

```html
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Both of which produce `hello hello`.

Comment: Try with something like `foo.innerHtml = 'bla    bla'.replace(' ', '&nbsp;')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Removing Whitespace When It Shouldn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213845/javascript-removing-whitespace-when-it-shouldnt)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[White space characters are usually collapsed in HTML (by default)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1).

You can replace it with the `&nbsp;` entity:

```
var text = text.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
```

`\s` will match any white space character, such as space, tab and new line. If you only want to replace space, use `/ /g` instead.

Other options which avoid string manipulation:

- Put the text in a [`pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4).
- Set the CSS 2 `white-space` property to `pre` as [@Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) pointed out. You can always add CSS properties dynamically to elements, they don't have to be specified in a style sheet.

Comment: well not always, you can use css like `white-space: pre;`

Comment: as someone said below, OP -> "Css in not an option"

Comment: also, strictly speaking \s !== '&nbsp;'. Just for the record.

Comment: @FelixKling - `var pr = document.createElement("pre"); pr.innerHTML = "hello         hello"; zlp.appendChild(pr);` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Without CSS there is _no way_ to preserve the exact behavior of normal consecutive spaces. The HTML white space entities such as `&nbsp;` does not wrap on line-break, which makes them similar but not the same. The other HTML white space entities such as `&thinsp;`, `&ensp;` and `&emsp;` also does not wrap. If CSS was an option, the `white-space: pre-line;` would be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

White space is collapsed in HTML. It's not a JS issue, the same would happen if you typed that manually in the HTML document. You need to replace the spaces with &nbsp;

```
zlp.innerHTML = "hello                hello".replace( / /g, "&nbsp;" );
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
zlp.innerHTML = "hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hello";
```

Like everyone else just said.

Answer (score 1):

use a html tag 'pre'

Example:

```
<pre>
A line
   A line with indent
</pre>
```

result:

```
A line
   A line with indent
```