# how to show Pretty Print JSON String in a JSP page

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to show a JSON string in a JSP page. I am working with Spring MVC framework. Below is the code

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url.toString(), String.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object json = mapper.readValue(result, Object.class);

String indented = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(json);

System.out.println(indented);//This print statement show correct way I need

model.addAttribute("response", (indented));
```

This line `System.out.println(indented);` prints out something like this-

```
{
  "attributes" : [ {
    "nm" : "ACCOUNT",
    "error" : "null SYS00019CancellationException in CoreImpl fetchAttributes\n java.util.concurrent.CancellationException\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:231)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.",
    "status" : "ERROR"
  } ]
}
```

which is the way I needed to be shown using a JSP page. But when I add it to model like this-

```
model.addAttribute("response", (indented));
```

And then shows it out in a resultform.jsp page like below-

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Response:</legend>
            <strong>${response}</strong><br />

    </fieldset>
```

I get something like this on the browser-

```
{ "attributes" : [ { "nm" : "ACCOUNT", "error" : "null    
SYS00019CancellationException in CoreImpl fetchAttributes\n 
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:231)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.", "status" : "ERROR" } ] }
```

which I don't need. I don't know why it get wrapped like this? I needed the way it got printed out above means like this.

```
{
  "attributes" : [ {
    "nm" : "ACCOUNT",
    "error" : "null SYS00019CancellationException in CoreImpl fetchAttributes\n java.util.concurrent.CancellationException\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:231)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.",
    "status" : "ERROR"
  } ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it got happened like this? And how can I show it in a JSP page the way I needed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[White space characters are usually collapsed in HTML (by default).](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) Such characters include newlines. Dump the JSON into a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/pre).

```
<pre>
${response}
</pre>
```

Other solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474709/139010

Comment: Thank you Matt a lot . This is exactly what i was looking for.