# How to add whitespace in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the codes below:

```
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({ SampleData: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))});
    var genRange = "       ";
    var genStan;

    $.each(viewModel.SampleData, function(idx, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            if(key.toString() === "GenabRange") { genRange = value; }
            if(key.toString() === "GenabStanine") { genStan = value; }
        });

        var obj = {
            GenReasoning: genRange + "        " + genStan
        };

        stud.push(obj);

    });
```

The whitespaces I've added "GenReasoning: genRange + "        " + genStan" doesn't work. What is the problem?

Can anyone help me with this?

Example results:

```
    GenabRange = Cat
    GenabStanine = Foo

    Output
       GenReasoning = Cat Foo

    Expected Output
       GenReasoning = Cat        Foo
```

Thanks

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What are you getting, and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: @Amadan He means the whitespace isn't being rendered...

Comment: Are you putting the contents of `obj.GenReasoning` into the HTML DOM?

Comment: @MarkGabriel good point, in which case the answer below won't work. I would suggest unicode

Comment: Is the first line JavaScript `@` ?

Comment: I would like to add unicode method: `/u0020`

Comment: @MarkGabriel, yes...

Comment: you can refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474696/how-to-preserve-whitespace-in-dynamically-added-javascript-dom-element

Comment: Note: While the question I chose as a duplicate deals with `\n`, the same applies to whitespace in general.

Comment: I used \u00A0 and it works fine now.,

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
var genRange = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

and this code:

```
var obj = {
    GenReasoning:genRange+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+genStan
};
```

Notes:

```
&nbsp; means 'non-breakable space',
browsers will render this as exactly 1 space
instead of combining them
```

Comment: This question was answered before, why not just redirect him?

Comment: It might be better if you explained to him what `&nbsp;` is rather than just spoonfeeding him the correct code. :D

Comment: @MarkGabriel, added explanation, not just 'spoonfeeding' anymore, :)

Comment: Tried this one but it doesn't work