# Why are padding spaces lost in my `select` element?

Tags: html

I have a `select` with the nice looking html below:

```
<select name="BundleId" readonly="readonly">
    <option value=""> - select a bundle - </option>
    <option value="DD62163A-B3D8-40DE-B033-C15B92D75222">  10 pts: R20</option>
    <option value="96B091D0-84DA-4F40-BBFE-3B04148C150E">  20 pts: R30</option>
    <option value="BDFEB546-2EF4-4E04-8B1E-4CD161FFC04A">  50 pts: R60</option>
    <option value="D0F1BEE6-1EB3-494C-948A-295C2C311900"> 100 pts: R110</option>
</select>
```

Note how I have, server side, padded the `option` elements' content, yet when I click the dropdown and view the options, the paddings are gone. Is there a special charater I should be using instead of space, or maybe pad with   values?

Comment: Did u try `&nbsp`  ?

Comment: This happens to any white space in any element. It's simply not used in that way in HTML. Try this as an example:

    `<p>         <-- whole lot of spaces</p>`

The spaces will appear as one space, if at all. I believe it will happen with `&nbsp;` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are padding spaces lost in my `select` element?

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) defines that the spaces following an opening tag or preceding a closing tag should be ignored:

> In order to avoid problems with SGML line break rules and inconsistencies among extant implementations, authors should not rely on user agents to render white space immediately after a start tag or immediately before an end tag.

There are other ways to encode white spaces in HTML and make them non-collapsing, e.g. `&emsp;`. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref.

Related: [How to preserve whitespace in dynamically added javascript DOM element without using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474696/218196) (for alterantive solutions).

Comment: Thank you for an inspiring answer. Yes, that first link is awesome; I have prominently bookmarked that first link for lots of future use. My server side padding is now:

`PadLeft(4, HtmlChars.Entities[HtmlEntities.Numsp].Char)`, where `Char` evaluates to character `0x2007`. In my Razor views, I can use `HtmlChars.Entities[HtmlEntities.Numsp].Html`, which evaluates to the string `&numsp;`. Now to start growing the `HtmlChars.Entities` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'padding' you mean you want the characters to line up like how you have in the example, you could try `$nbsp;` before the characters.

Example:

```
<option value="DD62163A-B3D8-40DE-B033-C15B92D75222">&nbsp;&nbsp;10 pts: R20</option>
<option value="96B091D0-84DA-4F40-BBFE-3B04148C150E">&nbsp;&nbsp;20 pts: R30</option>
<option value="BDFEB546-2EF4-4E04-8B1E-4CD161FFC04A">&nbsp;&nbsp;50 pts: R60</option>
<option value="D0F1BEE6-1EB3-494C-948A-295C2C311900">&nbsp;100 pts: R110</option>
```

If you are trying to do it via CSS, you can only add padding to the `select` box, and not the list that appears when you click on the dropdown box.

[View an example of this on Codepen](http://codepen.io/gnclmorais/pen/cHkqt)

The select box that says "Volvo" (the initial value) is styled, but when you click on it to select an option, you will see the default drop-down select. This is because it is handled by the browser and not rendered with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, multiple contiguous whitespace characters are normalized to a single space.  Use `&nbsp;` as a non-breaking space to prevent this, and to keep necessary spacing.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

Use `&nbsp;` its the equivalent of a space or use CSS

`option{
     padding-left: 2px /* or whatever value */
}`

Comment: I would love to use CSS, but the spaces are padding for a fixed length number, so vary between different `option` elements.

Comment: Can't you attach varied classes to the particular option elements and do it that way?

Comment: I feel that is a highly impractical solution. While number formatting is a presentation issue after all, having different classes for different length numbers only helps in situations where you hard code the `option` elements, a scenario I really do not favour. Or, you can  complicate life and use client script to add the correct class for each  option according to its content