# Loss of white space after split function, using RegExp method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

This is my problem:

```
var string = 'string     &        string';
let condition = /\S*(&)\S*/;
var array = string.split(condition);
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(i!==1){//array[1] is simply '&' in that case
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML+=array[i];
    }
}
//the output:
string             string
//but:
if string = 'string&string' the output is:
empty...
```

I can not just use replace or similar methods, because I'm handling a somewhat more complex code. This is just a simplified example of the problem.
My real problem is this: why do I lose the white space at the beginning and end of the strings that are the subject of the method split?
The css 'white space: pre' attribute does not work, so the problem is the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function does not remove whitespace:

```
➜  ~ node
> var string = 'string     &        string';
undefined
> let condition = /\S*(&)\S*/;
undefined
> var array = string.split(condition);
undefined
> array
[ 'string     ', '&', '        string' ]
```

Your CSS must be wrong because when [I tried your code with `white-space: pre` applied to `myDiv` it shows whitespace](https://jsfiddle.net/scdk5rsa/).

Comment: See this part:'//but:
if string = 'string&string' the output is:
empty...', with the var string = 'string     &        string'; me too don't have any problems, i have problems with 'string&string'.

Comment: I do not just divide by '&', and I have to take into account the character chosen for division from the string. Maybe I'd find a solution, I have to join these conditions: / \ s * \ B (#) \ s * / / \ s * \ b (#) \ s * /. And I would have the desired result.

Comment: If you need the split character in the result, then use `string.split(/(&)/)`

Comment: Thank you, this is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You lose the whitespace after the strings are added to the HTML in the line

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML+=array[i];
```

because HTML removes multiple whitespace characters.

Your CSS should look like:

```
#myDiv {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

You can also use the `<pre>` tag, if appropriate.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the output div with <pre> tags? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213845/javascript-removing-whitespace-when-it-shouldnt

Comment: Solved, see the Andy response.